# Changing name of Meta-inf

Tags: java, maven, meta-inf

I need to sent an email with zipped project which contains maven folders eg. - `META-INF`. My email don't allow me to sent such files (filltering emails). I need to change the name of that folder `META-INF`. Am I able to do that without losing the proper hierarchy of project?

Comment: You could write a script to do this transformation (and the reverse transformation at the other end).

Comment: Change it to `FOO-BAR` or whatever, then in the body of the email say "I, Michael, have changed the name of META-INF to FOO-BAR". Or better yet, do something sane like use Git.

Comment: I can't. It is needed to be fully functional - press start and it should compile, I can't change names directly

Comment: Then do something sane like use Nexus, Artifactory or better yet, a Docker Repository. Honestly, this is 2018 - sharing programs via email is not only inconvenient but unbelievably dangerous.

Comment: It's for recruitment purpose. It have to be throw mail, and ready to compile. Could you give me any other ideas ?

Comment: If you want to share code, then open a GitHub account upload the code and share the link. TBH, if a company I was applying for _didn't_ do that, I would be very troubled by their development practices...

Comment: As I said, I can't do that. I need to sent it via emai. I know how to do that for google disc's, github etc. but I need to follow the instruction

Comment: Upload the file to some file sharing service and send a link.

Comment: @lexicore wouldn't you be somewhat dubious of a company that shares code via a file sharing service - like we're in pre-CVS days? I would...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Somewhat dubious, yes. But not K.O. for me personally. Sometimes you have to put up with HR bullshit to get the position.

Comment: There is no way to change META-INF folder ? I can use only MAIL

Comment: No, this is not. This is part of the [jar spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html).